# create bar chart by accessing data from 2 .csv files

Tags: java, csv, bar-chart

`.csv` file 1 data:

```
sampler_label,aggregate_report_count,average,aggregate_report_median,aggregate_report_90%_line
HTTP Request1,  750               ,26339           ,22644               , 40210
HTTP Request2,  750               ,8280       ,4781              ,21016
```

`.csv` file 2 data:

```
sampler_label,aggregate_report_count,average,aggregate_report_median,aggregate_report_90%_line
HTTP Request1,  350               ,2539        ,2224                , 48410
HTTP Request4,  350               ,8736       ,9285              ,38217
```

I want to display bar graph, which should depict values of average from both files for each sampler label.
Here there are 2 average values in each file. there may be n number of values. in bar graph i want to display values of file 1 and file 2 in one graph only.
Please help me....

Comment: What you have tried ? Make an effort before posting a question.

Comment: actually i have found the solution now. i can plot the graph. but want the bars for 2 files to be displayed in different color. i am not getting it done.

Comment: and yah i made an effort before posting question. If u want i can post the whole code.

Comment: If you got the solution then post some part of code here and accept your own resolution. So that this post will not be part of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public JFreeChart createBarChartFromCSV() {     


csv csvReader = new csv();
        List<String[]> csvData1 = null;
                List<String[]> csvData2 = null;
        int indexOfAverage1 = 0;
                int indexOfAverage2 = 0;

        csvData1 = csvReader.getDataFromCSV1(csv.CSVFILENAME1);
                csvData2 = csvReader.getDataFromCSV2(csv.CSVFILENAME2);

        for(String[] columnArray : csvData1)
            for(int i = 0; i< columnArray.length; i++)
                if(columnArray[i].equalsIgnoreCase("average")){


enter code here

        indexOfAverage1 = i;
                    break;
                }

        if(indexOfAverage1 == 0){
            System.err.println("Error retrieving data from CSV File1 !!");
            System.exit(0);
        }


         for(String[] columnArray : csvData2)
            for(int j = 0; j< columnArray.length; j++)
                if(columnArray[j].equalsIgnoreCase("average")){
                    indexOfAverage2 = j;
            break;
                }

        if(indexOfAverage2 == 0){
            System.err.println("Error retrieving data from CSV File2 !!");
            System.exit(0);
}                


                JFreeChart barChart = generateBarChart(csvData1,csvData2, indexOfAverage1,indexOfAverage2);

        return barChart;
    }


    private JFreeChart generateBarChart(List<String[]> csvData1,List<String[]> csvData2, int columnIndex1, int columnIndex2){

        DefaultCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        final String YAXIS_NAME = csvData1.get(0)[columnIndex1]; //value returned is "average"
        final String XAXIS_NAME = csvData1.get(0)[0]; //value returned is "sampler_label"

        for(int i = 1; i < csvData1.size() - 1; i++){

            long averageValue1 = Long.parseLong(csvData1.get(i)[columnIndex1]);
            String columnKey1 = csvData1.get(i)[0];

            dataSet.setValue(averageValue1, YAXIS_NAME, columnKey1); // plot the graph
                        }


        for(int j = 1; j< csvData2.size() - 1; j++){

            long averageValue2 = Long.parseLong(csvData2.get(j)[columnIndex2]);
            String columnKey2 = csvData2.get(j)[0];

            dataSet.setValue(averageValue2, YAXIS_NAME, columnKey2); // plot the graph

        }

             System.out.println("created");

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("Comparison between the average of 2 values", XAXIS_NAME, YAXIS_NAME, dataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);      
        final CategoryPlot plot = chart.getCategoryPlot();
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);       
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        BarRenderer renderer=new BarRenderer();

      System.out.print( "set the range axis to display integers only...");
        final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());

          System.out.print( "disable bar outlines...");
        renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
        renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.10);


          System.out.print( "set up gradient paints for series...");
    final GradientPaint gp0 = new GradientPaint(
            0.0f, 0.0f, Color.blue, 
            0.0f, 0.0f, Color.lightGray
        );
        final GradientPaint gp1 = new GradientPaint(
            0.0f, 0.0f, Color.green, 
            0.0f, 0.0f, Color.lightGray
        );

        renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, gp0);
        renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, gp1);



                return chart;
    }
```